# Accessing common functions across multiple services

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm currently building an application, and as it stands I have a single service for each controller (the service handles the business logic for the controller).  Each service has it's own dbcontext.

I've recognised that several services need to perform the same functions (retrieve the same lists of data from the database and perform the same logic on them before returning them).  So ideally I need a way for the services to access common functions.

My first thought is to create a simple helper class that each service could use, with simple functions that take a dbcontext as one of the parameters, so that the functions could perform database queries as well as logic and return the result.

Is this a good idea?  Would I run into problems by structuring my code this way, or is there a better more robust and accepted approach I should take?

Answer (score 1):

I'd say you're on the right track, but go one step further with the single responsibility principle. http://blog.codinghorror.com/curlys-law-do-one-thing/. It's a proven strategy for keeping code clean. I avoid "helper" classes per say. They can get messy by having too many responsibilities. Instead I try to really think about what my class should do. Then I give it a really good name to remind me that it only does that one thing.

The fact that your services each have their own Db Context can be a problem. Just make sure that if you call upon more than 1 dependent service that you pass in the same Db context to them all. If your object graph is large, a container like AutoFac will be a big help.

Answer (score 1):

Is the data being returned the same? Are they using their own unique DB context or is it the same DB context?

Generally I would recommend avoiding creating a helper class. Generally a helper class is used to manipulate an object(s) rather than perform a database query.

Based on your comment there are two ways you could achieve this, one easier than the other.

**Option 1:**

If your application really is a simple one that you're not too concerned about doing things the 'correct' way then you could simply create base service class and update your services to extend it, and move your common database access into the base class, like so:

```
abstract class BaseService
{
    ...
    public ICollection<ExampleRecord> GetDatabaseRecords()
    {
        using (var context = new ApplicationDbContext())
        {
            /* Your DbContext code */
        }

        return databaseRecords;
     }       
    ...
}
```

Then extend `BaseService` like so:

```
public class ExampleService : BaseService
{
    ...

    public ICollection<ExampleRecord> GetRecords()
    {
        return this.GetDatabaseRecords();
    }

    ...
}
```

This would get the job done and be a better option to what you're currently doing, however it's generally not the best approach.

**Optios 2:**

If your application is more than a simple one and you're concerned about code maintainability then I would suggest looking into moving your database access code into a separate repository class and use an IoC container such as StructureMap to inject it the said repository into your services via dependency injection.

Personally I would recommend option 2 as it's far cleaner, more maintainable/extensible and you're not violating any of the [SOLID principles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29).

Comment: Yes, the db context is the same for all services; it is a simple application.  Your suggestion sounds a lot like Nacho Labordes.  To be clear, are you suggesting that I inherit all my services from an abstract base service class that contains common functions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an abstract service to define a common methods
This is a good tutorial about 
[generic repository, services layer, IoC, unit test an entity framework](http://techbrij.com/generic-repository-unit-of-work-entity-framework-unit-testing-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: How would this be implemented?  The link doesn't mention abstract services, or services that use functions outside of their class.

Comment: Create a base class(in this case EntityService) and define the common methods inside this